# How to exclude a widget from a GestureDetector in Flutter

Tags: flutter, button, gesturedetector

I set a Card inside a big black Container wrapped with a GestureDetector.
Now I want to set that little Card in the middle unclickable, which means that the only clickable part is the black container.

[image]

here is my Code:

```
  Widget LogOutCard () {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () { setState(() { isCardVisible = !isCardVisible; }); },
      child: Container(
        color: Color(0xcf000000),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 500.0,
            height: 150.0,
            child: Card(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.logout),
                    title: Text('log_out'.tr()),
                    subtitle: Text('Are_you_sure_to_log_out'),
                  ),
                  ButtonBar(
                    children: [
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('_cancel_'),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('_log_out_'),
       )],)],),),),),),);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) which makes it's child ignore touch gestures. Not sure if this will work for all of your requirements because it will probably also make those buttons unclickable.

For a popup like this, I'd suggest using the [showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) method and set barrierDismissible to true.

Comment: I tried with showDialog and it works better, thanks a lot